# convert non date format to date using mysql php

Tags: mysql

I have some database where the previous err...person has put the date format in as 20121218, is it possible to use this as a date in mysql so

```
SELECT substr(week_begin_date,0,4)+'-'+substr(week_begin_date,4,2)+'-'+substr(week_begin_date,6,8) 
AS startdate 
FROM table 
WHERE startdate < now()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD'` or `'YY-MM-DD'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31'`, `'2012/12/31'`, `'2012^12^31'`, and `'2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYMMDD'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523'` and `'070523'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23'`, but `'071332'` is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes `'0000-00-00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.

Therefore `20121218` is actually a valid date literal.  Therefore:

```
SELECT DATE(`week_begin_date`) AS `startdate`
FROM   `table`
WHERE  DATE(`week_begin_date`) < NOW()
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13b99/1/0).

However, for the longer-term, you would be wise to fix your schema (and, obviously, any application code that expects to read values in the existing format):

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY week_begin_date DATE
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/526d1/1/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this--

```
SELECT * from Table where STR_TO_DATE(substr(week_begin_date,0,4),substr(week_begin_date,4,2),substr(week_begin_date,6,8)','%d,%m,%Y') > now()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(week_begin_date,4,2)+"/"+SUBSTR(week_begin_date,6,8)+"/"+SUBSTR(week_begin_date,0,4),'%m/%d/%Y') AS startdate 
FROM table where STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(week_begin_date,4,2)+"/"+SUBSTR(week_begin_date,6,8)+"/"+SUBSTR(week_begin_date,0,4),'%m/%d/%Y') < now() ;
```

try this hope this will solve your prob